# What is causing this css border?

Tags: javascript, css, border

On my page, spec.itslimetime.net, there is a really odd silver border being applied directly below the nav menu only when the viewport is less than 500 px.  It must be javascript related because it only appears (fades in) once you scroll down the page a little bit.

I have searched high and low using dev tools.  Can anyone help me figure out where it is coming from?

Thanks.

Comment: "[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its this:

```
.header-3-startup-antiflicker {
    border-bottom: 1px #bdc3c7 solid;
}
```

which is inserted right at the bottom of your page.

Edit: But Jonathan Lonowski is right, this isn't really what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: My apologies. I wasn't aware this was not allowed?  Can you suggest an article or help document where I can learn more about how to use stack overflow properly?  I would like to play by the rules to be part of the community.

Comment: No worries, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help, that should get you started. Pretty much you have to ask an actual question rather than just posting something and saying that it isn't working. Btw did removing the css that I mentioned fix the issue?

Comment: It did solve my issue.  I am unsure why that css is there and also how you found it?  Did you right click on inspect element?  Because I spent about an hour poking around in there looking for it.

Comment: No idea why its there either. Yup I was using Chrome's element inspection tools and started by deleting the main elements one at a time to see if that removed it, which it didn't. I figured it had to be somewhere and saw that div at the bottom and sure enough that was it.